# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError with observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to access a rest api inside ngOnit as given below:-

```
 ngOnInit(): void {

    this.myModel = new myModel ();

     Observable.forkJoin(
        this.myService.getdata(),
            this.myService2.getData2(id)
    ).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.data1 = data[0];
            this.data2 = data[1];
        },
        err => { console.error(err); },
        () => {
            //other work
        });

}
```

on executing the above code i am getting below error:-

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
>   has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current
>   value: 'true'

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17572 This might be a bug, does it work if you use this hack: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17572#issuecomment-334943287

Comment: Thats right using the hack with setTimeout
eg:-
PanictUtil.getRequestObservable().subscribe(data => setTimeout(() => this.requesting = data, 0)); 

the code seems to work... but i am curious about why do i get this error. I am new to angular2 and little curious if i am missing any learning curve here

Answer (score 2):

try to use

```
this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
```

at the end of your method ,

... not forgetting to add

```
private _changeDetectionRef : ChangeDetectorRef
```

as parameter of the constructor of the Component owning your method.

See discution [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005)

Comment: This article explains why detectChanges call is not really a good solution to the problem, https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Comment: Thank you for the link @Brian Ogden

Comment: @Brian Ogden any other solutions?